# start with sshj

Tags: java, eclipse, ssh, sshj

I want to create a Java application to connect to my remote Linux server with ssh. Can someone send me some docs or tutorials to begin with sshj in eclipse (I'm working in a Windows environment).

Comment: Here's an example piece of code that will connect to a linux box up in AWS http://stackoverflow.com/a/15800383/311525

Comment: Sorry, but this is really not a question. You are just asking some one to do the search for you ...

Answer (score 9):

sshj has examples included with the source code:
https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples

Comment: The examples folder seems to be no more existent

Comment: https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples