# net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, sshj

first time asking on stackoverflow, and also using sshj. Besides the examples provided with sshj, I haven't really found any good resources to help using this API.

I've been trying to do remote port forwarding using sshj and have run into this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods
```

I tested the auth with a VM, but without using a public key. I would be using this to connect to an EC2 instance on which I know the login.

```
public void startRemotePortForwardingConnection(LocalPortForwarder.Parameters parameters) throws IOException{
    sshClient.connect(parameters.getLocalHost());
    this.connectionStatus = CONNECTED;
    System.out.print("Connected to localhost" + NEWLINE);

    try {
        sshClient.authPassword(this.username, this.password);
        System.out.print("Authorized with as user " + username + " with password " + password + NEWLINE);

        // the local port we should be listening on
        RemotePortForwarder.Forward localPortToListenOn = new RemotePortForwarder.Forward(parameters.getLocalPort());
        System.out.print("localPortToListenOn initialized" + NEWLINE);

        // where we should forward the packets
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(parameters.getRemoteHost(), parameters.getRemotePort());
        SocketForwardingConnectListener remotePortToForwardTo = new SocketForwardingConnectListener(socketAddress);
        System.out.print("remotePortToForwardTo initialized" + NEWLINE);

        //bind the forwarder to the correct ports
        sshClient.getRemotePortForwarder().bind(localPortToListenOn, remotePortToForwardTo);
        System.out.print("ports bound together" + NEWLINE);

        sshClient.getTransport().setHeartbeatInterval(30);
        sshClient.getTransport().join();
    }
    finally {
        sshClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Probably not the best (or even right) way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSHJ - Keypair login to EC2 instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283556/sshj-keypair-login-to-ec2-instance)

Comment: In my case, I tried to connect to `localhost` (Docker container with an SFTP server, atmoz/sftp). It worked after I changed the host to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Had same issue, what fixed it for me is using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example to a similar prior question that you can run directly in groovyconsole that will connect to an EC2 instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15800383/311525

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());`**. I send two configuration, first with public key, secound with username/password.

```
private static SSHClient setupSshj(String remoteHost, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
    client.connect(remoteHost);
    client.authPassword(username, password);
    return client;
}

private static SSHClient setupSshWithPublicKey(String remoteHost, int port, String username, String publicKey) throws Exception {
    SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
    client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
    client.connect(remoteHost, port);
    client.authPublickey(username, publicKey);
    return client;
}
```