# How can I do the equivalent of the IntelliJ database SSH tunnelling in my own code?

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, ssh

I am experimenting with an AWS RDS postgres instance that is sitting in a private subnet.

For access to my other private EC2 instances I have been using an [SSH bastion](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3N8GFK85UN1G6/Securely-connect-to-Linux-instances-running-in-a-private-Amazon-VPC).

This all works fine and great - but then I found out that IDEA can actually already help me access my private RDS instance.

All I had to do was configure the "Use SSH tunnel" section in the IDEA datasource settings:
[image: IDEA Datasource SSH tunnel settings]

Awesome, it worked - god damn I love IDEA.

But the question is... *how* does it work?

Is IDEA just doing some kind of crazy [SSH tunnelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283556/sshj-keypair-login-to-ec2-instance/15800383#15800383) for me behind the scenes (in which case, I'm even more impressed)?

Or is this a feature of the Postgres JDBC driver that I can leverage in my own code?  That is, is there some way I can configure the Postgres JDBC to do this SSH tunnelling to my RDS instance?

I really like the way this avoids having to have previously setup specific tunnelling configuration at the OS level, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835761/postgresql-via-ssh-tunnel/16838293#16838293).

So the question is: How can I do the same thing as IDEA is doing using only code in my project?

---

Accepted jdevelop's answer.

Here's the groovy snippet I used to test, for anyone else that might want to do this:

```
  JSch jsch = new JSch()
  jsch.addIdentity("~/mykeys/bastion.pem")
  jsch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
  Session session=jsch.getSession("ec2-user", bastionServer, 22)
  session.connect()

  int localPort = 65432
  session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, dbHostServer, dbHostPort)

  testDbConnection(
    "localhost", Integer.toString(localPort), dbName, dbUser, dbPassword)

  session.disconnect()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, IntelliJ does SSH tunnelling for you.

The easiest way of doing that in your code is to take a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and their [port forwarding example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html)